# How to compute $x_{2i}$ directly from $x_i$ in this $x^2 \mod N$ sequence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, factoring, gcd-and-lcm

$\DeclareMathOperator{\modulo}{mod}$
Let $x_0$ be an initial value less than $N$.  Let $f(x_{i+1}) = x^2_i
\modulo N$.  Then
\begin{align*}
  x_{2i} &= \overbrace{f(... (f(f}^{i\text{ times}}(x_i) \modulo N)) \modulo N ...) \modulo N
\end{align*}
Is there non recursive function $g$ such that $x_{2i} = g(x_i)$?  What is this function?  (I mean: what is its formula?  Can you find it?)  What if we ignore the modulus N?  Could we find it then?

Example. Let $f(x_{i+1}) = x^2_i \modulo N = 589$ with $x_0 = 3$.  Then
$(x_n) = 3, 9, 81, 82, 245, 536, 453,$ ...  Considering $x_6$ in terms of $x_3$ we find 
\begin{align*}
        x_6 &= 453\\
        &= f (536)\\
        &= f\left(f (245)\right)\\
        &= f\left(f\left(f(82)\right)\right)\\
        &= f\left(f\left(f(x_3)\right)\right)\\
        &= f\left(f (x^2_3)\right) \\
        &= f \left(x^2_3\right)^2\\ %% x^{2^2}_3
        &= \left(\left(x^2_3\right)^2\right)^2. %% x^{2^{2^2}}_3
\end{align*}

Can we get $x_6$ directly from $x_3$ without iterating $f$ for $6/2 = 3$ times?

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the definition notation. Either you notate as a succession, i.e. $x_{i+1}=x_i^2 \mod N$, or you notate it as a function, i.e. $f(i+1)=f(i)^2 \mod N$.

Comment: Well, it's eventually periodic (clearly)....so you can get it by simple look up.

Comment: I doubt there is anything simpler than $x_{2i}\equiv x_i^{2^i}\pmod N$. You see, $x_{2i}$ does not depend only on $x_i$. It also depends on $x_0$, and therefore also on $i$. If $G$ were such a superfunction then when you have $x_0=3$ you have $x_2=81$ and $x_4=245$, so $G(81)$ must be $245$. But, if you decided to use $x_0=9$ instead, then $x_1=81, x_2=82$, and we should have $G(81)=82$. So we are forced to have $i$ as a second input to $G$. Or, have a superquantumcomputer solving the "discrete log" problem of determining $i$ given $x_i$ and $x_0$.

Comment: @MicheleDePascalis Notation.  Point taken.  Maybe I overused notation.  The function $f$ is just the square function.  Sometimes I write $f$ sometimes I write the square.  (Maybe that was too much.)  It is definitely a succession.  (You can see that $f$ is applied over and over on the result of the previous $f$-application.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Very interesting insight.  (Grateful for it!)  But I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your comment.  If $x_{2i}$ doesn't depend only on $x_i$, shouldn't we see $x_0$ somewhere in your (correct) answer?

Comment: *Maybe* I get it.  It's not that $x_{2i}$ depends on both $x_0$ and $x_i$ at the same time.  We may write one formula where it depends on $x_0$ OR we may write a formula where it depends on $x_i$, but we don't need to write a formula that makes it depend on BOTH at the same time.  Do you agree?  In $x_i$ there is an implicit dependence on $x_0$ --- by definition, since the succession begins at $x_0$.  (Thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remainder class equivalence is a congruence with respect to multiplication, that is, $a \equiv b \bmod N$ and $c \equiv d \bmod N$ implies $ac \equiv bd \bmod N$. Now to be rigorous about why this is true we should be reasoning in terms of equivalence classes, but since you're taking the $\bmod$ operation as taking the remainder of the division, it should be enough for you to know that you can simply leave the remainder-taking at the end of any chain of summations and multiplications. So your succession is really:
$$
x_i= x_0^{\overbrace{2\cdot2\cdot\dots\cdot2}^{i\text{ times}}} \bmod N = x_0^{2^i} \bmod N
$$

Now, to answer your question, we can see that:
$$
x_{2i} = x_0^{2^{2i}} \bmod N = x_0^{2^i\cdot2^i} \bmod N = (x_0^{2^i})^{2^i} \bmod N = x_i^{2^i} \bmod N
$$
Notice that the last equivalence holds because $x_0^{2^i} \equiv x_i \mod N$.

Comment: Brilliant exposition of the required insights to solve the problem.  Your last equation shows not only the relationship of $x_{2i}$ to $x_i$ but also to $x_0$.  It's a privilege to have access to such feedback.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I do my best.